# vba sub function call time chell line Down Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have default test function call in vba. data first load in vba BICO() function successfully data load but line not drown in first sheet.
second function  is call data loaded data but line is drown in second function
this is my error.
I have Share in my code how to sale my broadloom . Any solution or any reference.

```
Sub test()
    Dim im, jm As Integer
    im = 1
    jm = 2
    Call BICO(i)
    Call ssp(j)
End Sub

Sub ssp(im)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    Dim a1 As String
    Dim a2 As String
    a1 = "A" & i
    a2 = "C" & i

    Range(a1, a2).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone

    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = "Saravanan"
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value = "Saravanan  S/No Ramsing, Pondichary -60089"
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value = "9791709616"
End Sub

Sub BICO(jm)
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2
    Dim a1 As String
    Dim a2 As String
    a1 = "A" & i
    a2 = "C" & i

    Range(a1, a2).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone

    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    Sheets(2).Cells(2, 1).Value = "Saravanan"
    Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2).Value = "Saravanan  S/No Ramsing, Pondichary -60089"
    Sheets(2).Cells(2, 3).Value = "9791709616"
End Sub
```

I Need two sheet drown the line using vba.
[image]

Data not line not display

[image]

This is lint it can drown now.

need sheet1 and sheet2 drow the grid line.

Comment: Use a macro recorder? Looks like you just want an all borders thin around your used range in the above.

Comment: Hi i have first test function call in side two function available one by one default value call now but sheet1 not  row 2 not border set. but sheet 2 row 2 border  set now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are having is to do with the fact that you don't qualify the worksheet you are selecting for the borders, the altered code below will point you in the right direction.

At the moment your code will simply look at the ActiveSheet as you are using `Range(a1, a2)` without telling the code which Worksheet you are referring to, so in actual fact the code is working, but drawing the borders twice on the same Worksheet, the amended code below will work as I've specified which Worksheet to update.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    i = 2
    j = 2
    Call BICO(i)
    Call ssp(j)
End Sub

Sub ssp(im)
    Dim wsSSP As Worksheet: Set wsSSP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim a1 As String
    Dim a2 As String
    a1 = "A" & im
    a2 = "C" & im

    wsSSP.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    wsSSP.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With wsSSP.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With wsSSP.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With wsSSP.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With wsSSP.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    wsSSP.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Saravanan"
    wsSSP.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Saravanan  S/No Ramsing, Pondichary -60089"
    wsSSP.Cells(2, 3).Value = "9791709616"
End Sub

Sub BICO(jm)
    Dim wsBICO As Worksheet: Set wsBICO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Dim a1 As String
    Dim a2 As String
    a1 = "A" & jm
    a2 = "C" & jm

    wsBICO.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    wsBICO.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With wsBICO.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With wsBICO.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With wsBICO.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With wsBICO.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    wsBICO.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Saravanan"
    wsBICO.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Saravanan  S/No Ramsing, Pondichary -60089"
    wsBICO.Cells(2, 3).Value = "9791709616"
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

To make the code more useful, as you are repeating the code for different worksheets, you could amend the Sub to take the worksheet as an argument, so that way you can call the same sub to affect different worksheets, please have a look at the code below:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    i = 2
    Call DrawBorder(i, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))
    Call DrawBorder(i, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2))
End Sub

Sub DrawBorder(im As Long, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim a1 As String, a2 As String
    a1 = "A" & im
    a2 = "C" & im

    ws.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    ws.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone

    With wsSSP.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With ws.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With ws.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With ws.Range(a1, a2).Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlSolid
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

    ws.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Saravanan"
    ws.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Saravanan  S/No Ramsing, Pondichary -60089"
    ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = "9791709616"
End Sub
```

Comment: @R.SaravanaKumar I've updated my answer to use the worksheet as an argument so you can use the same piece of code to apply the changes to different worksheets by simply amending the Call. Hope this helps :)